# How do bandwidth requirements for running a full node grow with blocksize?

Tags: network, full-node, bandwidth

I know they increase.

I'm looking for something more precise than that.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum bandwidth requirements for blocks previously (there is other traffic overhead including for transaction broadcasts if your node participates, the other traffic is variable depending on many factors mostly around network utilization) were ~1MB block *size* per ~10 minutes.

Now the max bandwidth for blocks is ~4MB block *weight* per ~10 minutes.

There is some information for current block size [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69468/what-is-the-current-maximum-bitcoin-block-size-in-mb).

Comment: So is the relationship basically linear?